# Can I return the base case as answer?

Tags: python

```
def encryption(n):
    if len(n) == 2:
        return n

    result = []

    for i in range(len(n) - 1):
        total = n[i] + n[i + 1]
        right_most_digit = total % 10


        result.append(right_most_digit)
        if len(result) > 2:
            result = encryption(result)

    return "".join([str(x) for x in result])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = [1, 5, 7, 9]
    print(encryption(numbers))
```

---

I need help with this code.
The problem is to add the two adjacent numbers and keep the right_most_digit, repeat the process to a point where only two numbers left, and return a string.
For example, 1+5, 5+7, 7+9 will be 6,2,6, then 6+2, 2+6 will be 8,8, then return 88 as a string.

Comment: Your code works for the given input. What is the issue?

Comment: Well, your base case does not return a string...it returns a list. So `encryption([1, 5])` will return the incorrect result. It also means input like `encryption([1, 5, 7, 9, 2])` will raise an exceptions. So I guess the answer is: no, you can't.

Comment: Are you required to write this as a recursive function? It it very simple with a `while` loop?

Comment: Instead of doing `return n` as the base case, maybe do `return "".join(n)` instead, to be consistent?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy if you return a string there it will raise an exception when you end up with a list of mixed types and you try to add them.

Answer (score 0):

With the least changes,

```
def encryption(n):
  if len(n) == 2:
    return n

  result = []

  for i in range(len(n) - 1):
    total = n[i] + n[i + 1]
    right_most_digit = total % 10


    result.append(right_most_digit)
    if len(result) > 2:
        result = encryption(result)

  return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
  numbers = [1, 5, 7, 9]
  print("".join([str(x) for x in encryption(numbers)]))
```

`print("".join([str(x) for x in encryption(numbers)]).lstrip("0"))` if you also want to strip any leading 0

Comment: You may want to double check the indenting here. Also, I'm not sure this gives the correct result for input like `numbers = [1, 5, 9, 9, 7]`. Unless I misunderstood, I would expect this to return `"26"`, but it returns `"28"`.

Comment: sorry the code formatting messed up the indentation, fixed it

Comment: I think the problem with the incorrect output is that `if len(result) > 2:` should be outside the `for` loop.

Comment: @Mark I expect the answer to be [0, 2, 6] which gives [2, 8]  so 28, not 26

Comment: Hmm. It seems like it should go: `[1, 5, 9, 9, 7]` -> `[6, 4, 8, 6]` - > `[0, 2, 4]` -> `[2, 6]` => `"26"` Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Mark The if statement and recursion should be intended.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it was an interview question so I can not change the code in the second part. So, I was able to get the correct answer with this test case, but if I increase the number list, like [1, 5, 7, 9, 10], it throws an error: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'. I think it's because I am doing it recursively, so basically, at some point, I am trying to append to a string, not a list. If there's another approach to this question, I would love to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about a different approach, you might consider not doing this recursively. You can simply keep processing the list in a `while` loop until the list is of length 2 or less. Then convert to a string:

```
def encryption(n):
    while len(n) > 2:
        n = [(a + b) % 10 for a, b in zip(n, n[1:])]
    return "".join([str(x) for x in n])

numbers = [1, 5, 7, 9]
print(encryption(numbers))
# 88
```

This is a little easier to reason about and it also makes it easy to debug by sticking a `print(n)` in the loops to see the progression.

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same thing while I was smoking LOL. I don't know why my head got stuck while I was in the interview... but I think it should be this easy. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, coding interviews play games with one's head.